# Removing wireplumber removes ubuntu-desktop

Tags: apt, package-management, 23.04

```
    sudo apt-get remove wireplumber
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-cantarell libwireplumber-0.4-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  pipewire-media-session
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal wireplumber
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pipewire-media-session
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 142 kB of archives.
After this operation, 62.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Any idea on how to avoid this and safely remove wireplumber, because it breaks audio,I reverted back to pluseaudio.
I am Using Ubuntu 23.04.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed `wireplumber`, `pipewire-media-session` was removed as both packages conflict with each other ... However, either package is essential for the desktop functionality ... Therefore, by installing `pipewire-media-session`, APT should take care of removing `wireplumber` safely like so:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install pipewire-media-session
.
.
.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  wireplumber
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pipewire-media-session
.
.
.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

`ubuntu-desktop` is a meta-package(*a "container" of multiple packages*) ... Some of those packages are essential and cannot be removed and the DE cannot function normally without them ... Therefore, if you remove any of those packages `ubuntu-desktop` will also be removed ... Some of them can be substituted with similar packages(*like the two "above mentioned" session managers for pipewire*), but even this can cause problems ... Better leave them alone(*i.e. no removal/substitution*).

Installing `pipewire-media-session` should only remove `wireplumber` ... `ubuntu-desktop` should not be removed at all ... However, I don't know what other package modifications you did on your system ... So be careful and read what APT prints as packages to be removed before you answer "yes" to it.

If, however, APT is still trying to remove `ubuntu-desktop`, then it means that other essential packages are missing … So, answer "no" to that and reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` like so:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

then, try again.

Comment: so that, by installing "pipewire-media-session", it will remove "wireplumber" and also "ubuntu-desktop", after this happened I have install "ubuntu-desktop" manually or it will handled by apt?

Comment: @ilovepeaceandplaying No, installing `pipewire-media-session` should only remove `wireplumber` ... `ubuntu-desktop` should not be removed at all ... However, I don't know what other package modifications you did on your system ... So be careful and read what APT prints as packages to be removed before you answer "yes" to it.

Comment: thanks @raffa, APT is trying to remove ubuntu-desktop for whatever reason, I don't know of.

Comment: @ilovepeaceandplaying `ubuntu-desktop` is a meta-package(*a "container" of multiple packages*) ... Some of those packages are essential and cannot be removed and the DE cannot function normally without them ... Therefore, if you remove any of those packages `ubuntu-desktop` will also be removed ... Some of them can be substituted with similar packages(*like the two "above mentioned" session managers for pipewire*), but even this can cause problems ... Better leave them alone(*no removal/substitution*)